# gdaldem slope calculation noData

Tags: slope, nodata, gdaldem

I use gdaldem to calculate the slope of a given region. This is the command I use:

```
gdaldem slope -s 111120 -p -compute_edges  N34E069.hgt N34E069_slope.tif
```

(I've got the SRTM data from http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm)

Some values in the raster band however have the noData value -9999. In the documentation I just came accross this line:

> The value -9999 is used as the output nodata value.

But, what is the reason for getting a nodata value? When I create a color-relief map with the following color code:

```
-9999 255 0 0 
0 255 255 255
90 0 0 0
```

I get the following output:
[image]

It seems like the noData values occur on the peaks of mountains. But on the left in the flat area I also get some noData values.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that the input DEM does not have nodata values? Otherwise is seems that from some reason slope=0 becomes nodata in the slope map.

Comment: Yeah, you were right! The input DEM file indeed had some strange values (-32768). I've used another file and now it works!